# Format list into correct string

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Hello i have a question to make a quiz.. i show my code >>>
My class is :

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer_prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer_prompt = answer_prompt
        self.answer = answer
```

and my main is :

```
from Question import Question

question_prompt = [
    "De quels couleur sont les bananes ?",
    "De quels couleur sont les pommes ?",
    "De quels couleur sont les fraises ?"
]

question1_answers_prompt = [
    "(a) Rouge\n",
    "(b) Jaune\n",
    "(c) Bleue\n\n",
]

question2_answers_prompt = [
    "(a) Rouge\n",
    "(b) Violette\n",
    "(c) Orange\n\n",
]

question3_answers_prompt = [
    "(a) Rouge\n",
    "(b) Verte\n",
    "(c) Jaune\n\n",
]
questions = [
    Question(question_prompt[0], question1_answers_prompt[:], 'b'),
    Question(question_prompt[1], question2_answers_prompt[:], 'a'),
    Question(question_prompt[2], question3_answers_prompt[:], 'a'),
]


def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    miss = 0
    answered = []

    for question in questions:
        print(question.prompt)
        answer = input(question.answer_prompt)

        answered.append(answer)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
        
    print(f"Tu as {score} / {len(questions)}")
    print(answered)
    

run_test(questions)
```

I trid some technique list comprehension but i can format correctly my `question_answers_prompt` list
I have something like this :

```
\>\>\> ['(a) Rouge\n', '(b) Jaune\n', '(c) Bleue\n\n']
```

and what i need is :

```
\>\>\> (a) Rouge
    (b) Jaune
    (c) Bleue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not add formatting in the `answers` definition

```
question1_answers_prompt = ["(a) Rouge", "(b) Jaune", "(c) Bleue", ]
question2_answers_prompt = ["(a) Rouge", "(b) Violette", "(c) Orange", ]
question3_answers_prompt = ["(a) Rouge", "(b) Verte", "(c) Jaune", ]
```

But only when using it

- You want a tab before each line, and a newline after each so format as such `f"\t{a}\n"`
- join when empty string to concat each answer line

```
for question in questions:
    print(question.prompt)
    answer = input("".join(f"\t{a}\n" for a in question.answer_prompt))
```

Giving

```
De quels couleur sont les bananes ?
        (a) Rouge
        (b) Jaune
        (c) Bleue
b
```

---

#### More style

Add a symbol to see the line to answer

```
for question in questions:
    print(question.prompt)
    print("\n".join(f"\t{a}" for a in question.answer_prompt))
    answer = input(">> ")

De quels couleur sont les bananes ?
        (a) Rouge
        (b) Jaune
        (c) Bleue
>> a
```

Comment: ohhh ok nice, yes this method is definit the best, (because i need make this for 100 question, are chose randomly --', so if i can write less is better thanks)

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you might want to join the elements of the list:

```
for question in questions:
    print(question.prompt)
    answer = input(''.join(question.answer_prompt))
    ....
```

Output:

```
De quels couleur sont les bananes ?
(a) Rouge
(b) Jaune
(c) Bleue

...
```

Comment: You didn't answer at all, and `input(''.join(question.answer_prompt))` is same as `input(''.join(a for a in question.answer_prompt))`

Answer (score 1):

I change only this line of your code : `answer = input(question.answer_prompt)` like below:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer_prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer_prompt = answer_prompt
        self.answer = answer

question_prompt = [
    "De quels couleur sont les bananes ?",
    "De quels couleur sont les pommes ?",
    "De quels couleur sont les fraises ?"
]

question1_answers_prompt = [
    "(a) Rouge\n",
    "(b) Jaune\n",
    "(c) Bleue\n\n",
]

question2_answers_prompt = [
    "(a) Rouge\n",
    "(b) Violette\n",
    "(c) Orange\n\n",
]

question3_answers_prompt = [
    "(a) Rouge\n",
    "(b) Verte\n",
    "(c) Jaune\n\n",
]
questions = [
    Question(question_prompt[0], question1_answers_prompt[:], 'b'),
    Question(question_prompt[1], question2_answers_prompt[:], 'a'),
    Question(question_prompt[2], question3_answers_prompt[:], 'a'),
]


def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    miss = 0
    answered = []

    for question in questions:
        print(question.prompt)
        answer = input(''.join(a for a in question.answer_prompt))

        answered.append(answer)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
        
    print(f"Tu as {score} / {len(questions)}")
    print(answered)
    

run_test(questions)
```

Comment: You may not need to paste ALL code given, if you didn't change it at all

Comment: Thanks, your method works too  I saved both methods in my sheet as the list comprehension is op.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I hadn't seen your badges, but both methods are equal, I voted for the first one I saw ^^'